# FOREIGN KEY constraint failed (code 787 SQLITE_CONSTRAINT_FOREIGNKEY) when add data to table room

Tags: kotlin, android-room

I have to tables CheckListModel and CheckListPoints, it is one to n relationship, when i try to add
data in DB CheckListModel adds correctly, but when code gose to add CheckListPoints i got this error. I have no idea why this happening

This is my DB

```
@Database(entities = [CheckListModel::class,CheckListPoints::class],version = 4,exportSchema = false)
abstract class CheckListDB : RoomDatabase() {

    abstract fun checkListDBDao():CheckListModelDBDao

    companion object {

        @Volatile
        private var instance: CheckListDB? = null

        fun getInstance(context: Context):CheckListDB{
            return instance ?: synchronized(this){
                instance?: buildDatabase(context).also { instance = it }
            }
        }
        private fun buildDatabase(context: Context): CheckListDB{
            return Room.databaseBuilder(context,CheckListDB::class.java,"check_list_model").fallbackToDestructiveMigration().build()
        }
    }
}
```

entityes

```
@Entity(
    tableName = "check_list_point",
    foreignKeys = [
        ForeignKey(entity = CheckListModel::class, parentColumns = ["checkListModelID"],childColumns = ["checkListColumnID"],onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE)
    ],
    indices = [Index("checkListColumnID")]
)
data class CheckListPoints(
    @ColumnInfo(name = "correctly")
    var correctly: Boolean,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "requirement")
    var requirement: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "passed")
    var passed: Boolean,
    @ColumnInfo(name="checkListColumnID")
    val checkListColumnID: Long,
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    val checkListPointsModelID: Long = 0L
): Serializable

@Entity(tableName = "check_list_model")
data class CheckListModel (
    @ColumnInfo(name = "check_list_name")
    val checkListName: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "check_list_count")
    val checkListCount: Int,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "check_list_result")
    val checkListResult: Int,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "description")
    val description: String,
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    val checkListModelID: Long = 0L
        ) : Serializable
```

relationship

```
data class CheckListWithCheckListModel(
    @Embedded val CheckList: CheckListModel,
    @Relation(
        parentColumn = "checkListModelID",
        entityColumn = "checkListColumnID"
    )
    val checkListPoints: List<CheckListPoints>
)
```

this is dao

```
@Dao
interface CheckListModelDBDao {

    @Insert
    fun insertCheckList(data:CheckListModel)

    @Insert
    fun insertCheckListPoint(vararg data:CheckListPoints)

    @Delete
    fun deleteCheckList(checkList: CheckListModel)

    @Transaction
    @Query("SELECT * FROM check_list_model " )
    fun getEverything(): Flow<List<CheckListWithCheckListModel>>
}
```

and this is how i add

```
    private var doorCheckListModel = CheckListModel("Дверь",0,0,"4321")
    private val doorCheckListPoint1 = CheckListPoints(false,"1",false,doorCheckListModel.checkListModelID)
    private val doorCheckListPoint2 = CheckListPoints(false,"2",false,doorCheckListModel.checkListModelID)
    private var doorListOfCheckListPoints = listOf<CheckListPoints>(doorCheckListPoint1,doorCheckListPoint2)

    private var windowCheckListModel = CheckListModel("Окно",0,0,"4321")
    private var windowCheckListPoint1 = CheckListPoints(false,"1",false,windowCheckListModel.checkListModelID)
    private var windowCheckListPoint2 = CheckListPoints(false,"1",false,windowCheckListModel.checkListModelID)
    private var windowListOfCheckListPoints = listOf<CheckListPoints>(windowCheckListPoint1,windowCheckListPoint2)

    var checkLists = MutableLiveData<List<CheckListModel>>().apply {
        value = listOf(doorCheckListModel,windowCheckListModel)
    }

    fun addCheckList(name: String){
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            when (name) {
                "Дверь" -> insert(doorCheckListModel,doorListOfCheckListPoints)
                "Окно" -> insert(windowCheckListModel,windowListOfCheckListPoints)
            }
        }
    }

    private suspend fun insert(checkList: CheckListModel, checkListPoints: List<CheckListPoints>){
        database.insertCheckList(checkList)
        for(checkListPoint in checkListPoints){
            database.insertCheckListPoint(checkListPoint)
        }
    }
}
```

also i display data from CheckListModel in fragment. CheckListModel added to DB Correctly and display correctly, but CheckListPoints has not

Comment: share logcat error here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create `doorCheckListModel`, its `checkListModelID` is initially 0. You use this 0 as `checkListColumnID` in `doorCheckListPoint1`. So when you save the `CheckListModel`, Room automatically generates the primary key and saves in the table. Similar is the case for primary key in `CheckListPoints` table. But the entries saved in `CheckListPoints` table still have 0 in `checkListColumnID` column.

This is why the foreign key constraint is failing. There is no `CheckListModel` with 0 as its primary key. To fix this, you will have to set the value of `checkListColumnID` before saving a `CheckListPoints` entry in the table.

If you go through Room [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/accessing-data#convenience-insert), the @Insert annotated function can optionally return the rowId for the inserted item. For integer primary keys, rowId is the same as primary key.

Try this code:

```kotlin
// Return the primary key here
@Insert
fun insertCheckList(data:CheckListModel): Long
```

```kotlin
private suspend fun insert(checkList: CheckListModel, checkListPoints: List<CheckListPoints>){
    val id = database.insertCheckList(checkList)
    for(checkListPoint in checkListPoints){
        database.insertCheckListPoint(checkListPoint.copy(checkListColumnID = id))
    }
}
```